# Saving an object to DynamoDB instance via NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but the documentation is a bit confusing for DynamoDB, especially for NodeJS (I do see a lot for Java, however!).

I've done quite a bit of searching and only have found questions pertaining to the old SDK, so hopefully this isn't a duplicate question!

I'm trying to store a Javascript object into my DynamoDB instance. The error I'm getting and the code I'm using is outlined below.

Error:

```
Unable to add item. Error JSON: {
    "message": "One or more parameter values were invalid:
       Type mismatch for key File expected: S actual: M",
    "code": "ValidationException",
    "time": "2016-10-29T19:36:02.317Z",
    "requestId": [removed],
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 0
}
```

Code:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var docClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    "accessKeyId": AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    "secretAccessKey": AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: 'us-east-1',
    endpoint: "https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
});
var tableName = AWS_TABLE_NAME;
var params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    Item: {
        ProjID: projID,
        File: {
            name: fileName,
            url: fileUrl
        }
    }
};
docClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
    callback(true);
});
```

Once again, I'm sure it's a fairly simple issue - I just haven't quite found any documentation to help me out that's updated.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is File an attribute in the schema of your table? If it is and it's defined as a String, then the error you are getting is just indicating that you are trying to put a map into a string attribute.

DynamoDB only supports String and Numeric keys so you'll have to revisit your design. Perhaps you can store the File information as a string for the key and then expanded as a map into a separate attribute if need be.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up stringifying the Javascript Object and then to get it, re-parsing it as an Object.